# Can this algorithm be reversed?

Tags: python

Hi I have the following python code.

> Note... yes, I am asking you to solve my algorithm.. I have become burnt out
>   working on it. If you fancy a challenge give it a go.

```
dataListEdited = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0]    #This is just random 1's and 0's

patternsNotAllowed = [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,0]]

#Condition data
def conditionData(dataListEdited,patternsNotAllowed):
    offset=0
    for x in range(len(dataListEdited)):
        print(dataListEdited[:x+1])
        for notAllowed in patternsNotAllowed:
            if(len(dataListEdited[:x+1])> len(notAllowed)-1):
                if((dataListEdited[(x+1)-len(notAllowed):x+1]) == notAllowed):
                    print("Matched"+str(notAllowed))
                    lenToFlip = len(dataListEdited) - x +1
                    print(dataListEdited)
                    print("Swap @" + str(lenToFlip-1))
                    for y in range(lenToFlip-1):
                        if(not(dataListEdited[-y-1]) == True):
                            dataListEdited[-y-1] = 1
                        else:
                            dataListEdited[-y-1] = 0
                    print(dataListEdited)
                    offset = x
                    break
    return dataListEdited
```

Please analyse if you wish, but it basically looks at the list dataListEdited and makes sure that it doesn't contain any of the lists in patternsNotAllowed.

It does this by checking if there is a case in patternsNotAllowed which matches a portion of the sequence dataListEdited, if a match is found it flips the last bit that caused the match in dataListEdited and all bits to the right of that bit are also flipped.

My question is this;

> **Is the process above reversible?**

I have been trying to figure this out myself the last week and I just can't... Below is some code I have tried. (it goes backwards doing the same thing, but obviously doesn't work). Also I am aware you could store the locations where flips have happened to reverse them but I want to avoid doing this. (but i'm starting to think it's impossible).

```
def unconditionData(dataListEdited,patternsNotAllowed):
    for x in range(len(dataListEdited)):
        if(not(dataListEdited[-1-x]) == True):
            dataListEdited[-1-x] = 1
        else:
            dataListEdited[-1-x] = 0
        #print(dataListEdited)
        for notAllowed in patternsNotAllowed:
            #print(dataListEdited[len(dataListEdited)- x - len(notAllowed):len(dataListEdited)-x])
            if(dataListEdited[len(dataListEdited)- x - len(notAllowed):len(dataListEdited)-x] == notAllowed):
                print("Matched " + str(notAllowed))
                lastFlipPoint = len(dataListEdited)- x
                break

    return dataListEdited
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Woody

Comment: Intuitively it doesn't seem reversible. How can you tell if a bit is the result of flipping or the original value?

Comment: `len(dataListEdited[:x+1])` isn't that the same as `x`?

Comment: x+1 but yes @Barmar

Comment: I guess my question is more along the lines of how would I do this :L perhaps even changing the way I avoid the sequences I don't want needs to be changed?

Comment: I don't understand that question. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not reversible.

If `patternsNotAllowed = [[0]]`, you'll get the same result `[1, 1]` from an input list `[0, 1]` and `[1, 1]`.

Since there are multiple inputs with the same output, there's no way to tell which input produced the output, so you can't reverse it to the actual input.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Barmar's answer, it is not reversible using your own `patternsNotAllowed` list, either. There are 2^13 = 8192 different lists of length 13 containing just 0s and 1s, and we can try them all using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
>>> len({
...     tuple(conditionData(list(a), patternsNotAllowed))
...     for a in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=13)
... })
...
178
```

(I removed all the print statements to test this.) By putting them into a set and finding the length, we can see there are only 178 distinct outputs, so each output has on average 8192/178 ≈ 46 different pre-images.

Comment: More generally, I think all the intermediate states that the list goes through are possible inputs that will produce the same output.